# how to click on a table row using capybara & rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, capybara, rspec-rails

I am writitng request spec for my rails app with capybara. In my code I have something like:

```
%table
  %tbody
     %tr{"on_click" => "location.href='some_link'"}
       %td="Some attribute"
       %td="Some attribute"
       %td="Some attribute"
       %td="Some attribute"
```

This way I make the entire row clickable. I want to write a request spec with capybara for this feature but I don't know how. Can anyone help me on this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you should first get to know the testing in rails. Check this out! http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test it is really helpful. You can give your `tr` a class (say) `.tr` and do

`page.find(:css, ".tr").click()`

I hope this works, worked in my case!

Comment: If I don't want to give it a class name, then what I am thinking is to  do sth like:

page.find('.table.tbody.tr', :text => "the entire row").click

However I don't know how to write "the entire row" properly. From the code I wrote above, it can be "Some attribute Some attribute Some attribute Some attribute" but that doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't remember the exact syntax but may be you can do something like page.find(:xpath, ".//table/tbody/tr[1]").click()!

Answer (score 5):

I found this works without requiring a class:

```
page.find(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr").click
```

I believe your row-click requires JavaScript, so you'll need to add `:js => true` to your test's header. Setting up testing with JavaScript is a challenge. I found these resources helpful:

- [ASCIIcast #257 Request Specs and Capybara](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast) - see info on database-cleaner
- [Capybara readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#readme) - see “Transactions and Database Setup"

Here is a more complete test example:

```
# Note that opening page by clicking on row requires JavaScript
describe "when user clicks on first row", :js => true do

  let(:first_account_listed) { Account.order(:name).first }

  before { page.find(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr").click }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Account Details') }

end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Capybara 3+ you can go with a more elegant way by using the `:table_row` selector and match against a `td` value like:

```
page.find(:table_row, ["Some attribute"]).click
```

If you have table headers defined you can also pass a Hash instead of an Array that will match the cell against its corresponding table header like this:

```
page.find(:table_row, { "Header" => "Cell value" }).click
```

To dive into how this actually works, here's a link to the latest Capybara selector definition: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector/definition/table_row.rb

Comment: Note that there is currently a bug which requires the curly braces when using the hash syntax. So this wouldn't work: `page.find(:table_row, "Header" => "Cell value")`